# Implement if/else

Tags: android, string, if-statement

I want to implement this code to set the color of navigation bar if the Android Version is above 5.X.X :

How I can implement the if-statement?

- EDIT:

For those who want to:

```
String _OSVERSION =
        android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    if (_OSVERSION.toString().startsWith("5"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Android Version are: \n\n" + _OSVERSION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Window window = this.getWindow();

        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.indigodark));

        window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.indigodark));

    }

    else if (_OSVERSION.toString().startsWith("6"))
    {

        Window window = this.getWindow();

        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.indigodark));

        window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.indigodark));

    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your android version is under 5.X.X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
          Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ) {

//Code
}
```

Comment: Worked :D thanks Jas. I will edit with the codes with I implemented for the differences.